# Rails index on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

What is the standard practice for a rails app when a standard 'show.html.erb' for one model essentially just lists its `has_many` of another model? There is no `index` for the 'child' model as without the context of its 'parent' model, a list of them would be useless.

Creating /parents/1/children/1 feels like the right thing to do (especially in terms of the API) and yet on the /parents/1 page there would be nothing but a bit button saying "carry on" ... again, useless.

Do I creat separate routes, like the one above, purely for the API or am I missing a cleaner more 'Railsy' way.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure the above is totally clear.  If I have an `Exam` that was completely made up of `Questions`, would the Rails way to be to link to `/exam/1/questions` or purely to `/exam/1` with a list of questions.  Obviously the API would go to `/exam/1/questions` in most cases but what about the standard HTML page?  It would seem like it wants to be `/exam/1` but with nested resources the `create` route (by default) goes to the `/exam/1/questions` route. If there is a validation error on the `/exam/1/questions/new` route the form is rendered again on the `create` (`/exam/1/questions`) route; if the page is then refreshed you then get a 404 error as there is no index for the children.

All this leads me to believe that Rails expects be an `index` action for the majority of models; but in the above example this feels odd.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you dont whant the route to `/parents/1` to be on your path. For this reason you should specify it in your `routes.rb`

```
resource :parents, except: :show do
  resource :children
end
```